# How do I connect to Ganache with ethers?

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ganache

```
const ethers = require("ethers");
const fs = require("fs-extra");

async function main() {
  // http://127.0.0.1:7545
  // Compile in our code
  // Compile them seperately
  const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("http://127.0.0.1:7545");
  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(
    "0x578f756dd1e637bb78dff004cff8517f384f3be491cce3147e4a4f53bcbb8396",
    provider
  );
  const abi = fs.readFileSync("./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi", "utf8");
  const binary = fs.readFileSync("SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.bin", "utf8");
  const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, binary, wallet);

  console.log("Deploying, please wait...");
  const contract = await contractFactory.deploy(); 
  console.log(contract);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

The Error is:

JsonRpcProvider failed to `startup; retry in 1s
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7545
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) {
errno: -111,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 7545

I thought maybe port 7545 was closed so I ran the netstat command and it seems to be open and listening. I'm a little lost. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: This is what I got from the netstat command: [Ganache.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51068        DEV33:7545             ESTABLISHED
 [Ganache.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51073        DEV33:7545             ESTABLISHED
 [Ganache.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51074        DEV33:7545             ESTABLISHED
 [Ganache.exe]
  TCP    172.17.144.1:139       DEV33:0                LISTENING

Answer (score 1):

My Problem Is solve by changing the ganache server to wifi
and try this port 8545;
First Change the ganache server by go to setting and then go to server tab.
and try this port with jsonRpcProvider function/
http://192.168.100.9:8545
Try This And You Error Will Be Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac m2 on Ventura OS, in the Ganache app, go to settings -> server -> change the hostname of the Ganache server to 192.168.10.128. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7k7u.png)

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who is taking the free code camp / pat collins course (or anyone on a WSL + Ganache setup really) you're going to want to edit the ganache server settings (top right gear icon>server tab) to go by vEthernet http://172.24.240.1 so your ganache and ethers can connect

Answer (score 0):

As a fork of Flasgod's answer:

I am working through the free code camp / pat collins course and I'm working in the WSL environment.

Switching to the vEthernet server inside of ganache (top right gear icon>server tab) did not work for me. I believe this is because I am trying to run my deploy code inside the WSL: Ubuntu environment while ganache is running on my Windows desktop. They couldn't connect to each other.

Solution:

- Follow [these directions](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache#getting-started) from the truffle/ganache github to install and use ganache in the WSL command line.

  - This way, ganache is running inside the WSL environment along side the deploy code.
- run `ganache` in the WSL command line.
- Use the private key and "listening on" ip displayed in the terminal.

  - ip should still be formatted "http://x.x.x.x:xxxx" in the code.
- Open up a new terminal window so ganache continues to run in the first window.
- run `node deploy.js`

This solved my problem.